# Difference between jpeg byte array and bitmap byte array

Tags: c#, image, type-conversion, arrays, jpeg

I am doing some image processing in C# and need help understand the differences between the raw data of different image formats.

I am capturing a 640x480, 30 frames a second RGB stream from a camera and I want to write this to disk as each frame is displayed and display on a WPF canvas object at the same time.

Using Binary Writer I can write the byte[] data of the image to disk easily enough and I can easily convert this to a writeable bitmap to display in the canvas.

What I dont understand is this.  Is the raw data (byte[] imageData) of a JPEG different (smaller in size) to the raw data of a bitmap?  If it is, would it make more sense to convert every RGB image to JPEG then get the byte array for that JPEG and then write that information to disk?

Apologies if that sounds like I have a simple view on this but I'm relatively knew to this type of programming.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Jpegs are compressed, bitmaps are not.. Did I miss something?

Comment: Jpegs are 99% of the times lossy compressed, bitmaps are not...

Comment: This means that JPegs throw away a bit (or even a lot) of the data when they are made.

Comment: raw data isn't the same as jpeg data, like Sayse said, it's compressed. But compressing/decompressing raw data takes cpu power, and jpeg format is a lossy format, so you will lose quality. I think, you should consider whether the size on disk matters vs the cpu power to record the frames and compress them to jpeg.

Comment: For "capturing a 640x480, 30 frames a second RGB stream from a camera" it *sounds* like JPEG is a better option than raw RGB pixels. JPEGs are certainly going to save you some bytes. But it depends on wether you can live with the slightly reduced quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "raw data", the bit in memory, are the same for jpeg, bmp or png, they vary only for the size of the image (width, height), and pixel format, (rgb, argb, etc...)